# Find and remove from linked lists using head_return and tail_return

Tags: c++, linked-list

I'm working through a linked list example. I am at the find and remove function which traverses the list to find a particular element. The find_remove function does not work. All other functions within the application work (head_return, tail_return, etc.)

I would be grateful if someone could point out where I am going wrong with find_remove.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct node_ll
{
    int payload;
    node_ll* next;//Pointer to the next node
};

void head_insert(node_ll** list, int pload)
{
    node_ll* temp = new node_ll;//Create a new node, and let temp be the address of that node.
    temp->payload = pload;//Set the payload of the struct whose address is temp to pload.
    temp->next = *list;//Set the next of the struct whose address is temp to the address of the old head of the list.
    *list = temp;//The address of the old head of the list is changed to the address of the struct temp.
};

void tail_insert(node_ll** list, int pload)
{
    if (*list == NULL)
    {
        head_insert(list, pload);
    }
    else
    {
        node_ll* temp = new node_ll;
        for (temp = *list; temp->next; temp = temp->next);
        temp->next = new node_ll;
        temp->next->payload = pload;
        temp->next->next = NULL;
    }
}

int head_return (node_ll** list)
{
    if (*list != NULL)
    {
    int temp = (*list)->payload;
      node_ll* trash = *list;
      *list = (*list)->next;
      delete trash;
      return temp;
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}

int tail_return (node_ll** list)
{
    if (*list != NULL)
    {
      if ((*list)->next == NULL)
        {
            return head_return(list);
        }
        else
        {
      node_ll* trash;
            for (trash = *list; trash->next->next; trash = trash->next);
            int temp = trash->next->payload;
            delete trash->next;
            trash->next = NULL;
            return temp;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}

void find_remove (node_ll** list, int pload)
{
    if (*list != NULL)
    {
        node_ll* temp;//Declared before loop for use after loop.
        for (temp = *list; temp->next; temp = temp->next)
        {
            if (temp->payload == pload)
            {
                int trash = head_return(&temp);
            }
        }
        if (temp->payload == pload)
        {
            int trash = tail_return(list);
        }
    }
}

void print_ll (node_ll** list)
{
  node_ll* temp = *list;//Let temp be the address of the node that is the head of the list.
    while(temp)// != NULL
    {
        cout << temp->payload << endl;//Print out payload of the struct whose address is temp.
        temp = temp->next;//Set the address of temp equal to the address stored in next of the struct whose address is temp.
    }
}

int main()
{
    node_ll *blist = NULL;
    tail_insert(&blist, 2);
    tail_insert(&blist, 4);
    tail_insert(&blist, 6);
    find_remove(&blist, 4);
    print_ll(&blist);
    cout << '\n';

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

**EDIT**:

Here is my attempt at rewriting your code.

```
void find_remove (node_ll** list, int pload)
{
    if (*list != NULL)
    {
        while (*list && (*list)->payload == pload)
        {
            head_return(list);
        }
        if (*list != NULL)
        {
            node_ll* temp;
            for (temp = *list; temp->next->next; temp = temp->next)
            {
                if (temp->next->payload == pload)
                {
                    node_ll* trash = temp->next;
                    temp->next = temp->next->next;
                    head_return(&trash);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT 2:**
Thank you! This new solution works if there are multiple matchine nodes at the start, multiple matching nodes in the middle or multiple matching nodes at the end.

```
void find_remove (node_ll** list, int pload)
{
    if (*list != NULL)
    {
        while (*list && (*list)->payload == pload)
        {
            head_return(list);
        }
        if (*list != NULL)
        {
            node_ll* temp;
            for (temp = *list; temp->next; temp = temp->next)
            {
                while (temp->next->next != NULL && temp->next->payload == pload)
                {
                    node_ll* trash = temp->next;
                    temp->next = temp->next->next;
                    head_return(&trash);
                }
            }
            if (temp->next == NULL && temp->payload == pload)
            {
                tail_return(list);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean when you say "does not work"?

Comment: If I pass a 6 to the find_remove function to find and remove the last element in the list, it works as a find_remove function should. If I pass a number which is not at the end of the list, the application crashes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The crash is due to the fact that your loop logic is not correct, also you are not keeping track of the previous node which means you are not correctly resetting the linked list, this is the simplest fix:

```
void find_remove (node_ll** list, int pload)
{
    if (*list != NULL)
    {
        node_ll* temp, *prev=NULL;//Declared before loop for use after loop.
        for (temp = *list; temp != NULL; temp = temp->next)
        {
            if (temp->payload == pload)
            {
               if( NULL != prev )
               {
                  prev->next = temp->next ;
               }
                int trash = head_return(&temp);
            }

            prev=temp ;
         }
   }
}
```

Although honestly the code has a lot of style issues and is a lot more like C-style code than C++ style code. You may want to consider checking out [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

**update:**

If you change this in your modified code it works:

```
for (temp = *list; temp->next != NULL; temp = temp->next)
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

At the top of the loop you never know if `temp->next` is NULL so doing `temp->next->next` is never valid.

Comment: Thank you, for the answer and the recommendation to code review. I have attempted to rewrite your code, and am experiencing another error. node_ll* temp;
   for (temp = *list; temp->next->next; temp = temp->next)
   {
    if (temp->next->payload == pload)
    {
     node_ll* trash = temp->next;
     temp->next = temp->next->next;
     head_return(&trash);
    }
   }

Comment: @DannyRancher It is really hard to read code put in a comment, I would advise updating the question with an update section if you need to post updates. A quick glance, I can tell you in general `temp->next->next` is not a good idea since you need to check `temp->next` is valid first.

Comment: I have edited my original post. temp->next should be valid since in the loop, I test for temp->next->next to be not null.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I have completed the example to my specification. I also posted the code on codereview in search for more tips and perhaps a more compact solution to some of the more complex functions ordered_insert and find_remove. http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/25043/singly-linked-list-for-review-c